# Swing - не рисуется Graphics на JPanel

Tags: jpanel, swing, java, graphics

Почему рисуется только линия (0,0)-(100,100), указанная в перегруженном paint'e, но не отображаются фигуры, нарисованные в Main'e?

Насколько я понимаю, при repaint() в paint(Graphics g) автоматически передаётся Graphics объекта. Но изменения графики, сделанные в Main'e почему-то не отображаются.

---

```
package sandbox;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7362977924195873951L;
    MyPanel main_panel;
    Graphics gr;

    public Main() {
        main_panel = new MyPanel();
        this.setContentPane(main_panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setResizable(false);
        pack();

        gr = main_panel.getGraphics();
        gr.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 255));
        gr.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        gr.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
        main_panel.repaint();
        this.repaint();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5120203616437379506L;
        MyPanel() { setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400)); }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {
            super.paint(g);
            g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Swing каждый компонент отрисовывает сам себя в методе paintComponent(Graphics g). То-есть при вызове метода repaint() вызовется этот метод, в котором сказано только про нарисованную линию - то, что в методе main нигде не сохранится. Если вы хотите рисовать на компоненте, храните то, что хотите нарисовать в переменной и передавайте в метод paintComponent()

Comment: Замена `this.repaint()` на `main_panel.paintComponents(gr)` ничего не дает. Нельзя ли пояснит по-подробнее?